# char型のハミング重みとハミング距離を計算したい。

Tags: c++, c

c++でchar型のハミング重みとハミング距離を計算したいです。
ハミング重みとはビット列の中に含まれる1の数で、ハミング距離とは2つのビット列の異なるビットの数です。

例えば

```
a = 1010
b = 1111
```

ならば

ハミング重みはa=2,b=4です。
a,bのハミング距離は2です。

もし、これらは配列であれば簡単ですが、char型のまま求めることは可能でしょうか。また、もし直接できなければchar型を2進数の配列に変換することはできますでしょうか。

Answer (score 13, accepted):

c 言語の機能だけで実現できます。具体的には、 bitwise 演算を用いて、 bit が立っている個数を計算します。ハミング距離を計算するには、2つの char の xor 演算を取った結果に対して、 bit の個数を計算します。
以下の `total_bits` の実装にはいくつも hack っぽい方法があるのですが、解りやすい実装は次です。

```
#include <stdio.h>


int total_bits(unsigned char v) {
    unsigned int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v

    for (c = 0; v; v >>= 1) {
        c += v & 1;
    }
    return c;
}


int main() {
    char a = 0x0a;
    char b = 0x0f;

    printf("a: %d\n", total_bits(a));
    printf("b: %d\n", total_bits(b));
    printf("hamming(a,b): %d\n", total_bits(a ^ b));

}
```

出力

```
a: 2
b: 4
hamming(a,b): 2
```

---

参考: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html の counting bitsets

より効率的な方法を知りたければ、上記のサイトを見てみると、いろいろ方法が書いて有ります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 11):

C++の標準ライブラリにはビット集合を扱うクラスstd::bitsetがありますので、それに任せるという選択肢もあります。

```
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char a = 0x0a;
    char b = 0x0f;

    std::bitset<CHAR_BIT> as(a);
    std::bitset<CHAR_BIT> bs(b);
    std::bitset<CHAR_BIT> as_xor_bs(as ^ bs);
    std::cout << "a  (" << as        << "): " << as.count()        << '\n';
    std::cout << "b  (" << bs        << "): " << bs.count()        << '\n';
    std::cout << "a^b(" << as_xor_bs << "): " << as_xor_bs.count() << '\n';
}
```

出力

```
a  (00001010): 2
b  (00001111): 4
a^b(00000101): 2
```

Answer (score 10):

蛇足で、ハミング重みを計算する関数（Yuki Inoueさんの書かれた`total_bits()`）が最近のコンパイラーには実装されています。

- [GCC 3.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html)の__builtin_popcount
- [LLVM 1.5](http://llvm.org/releases/1.5/docs/ReleaseNotes.html)の__builtin_popcount
- [Visual Studio 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/10/18/new-intrinsic-support-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx)の__popcnt

なぜ各コンパイラーがこぞってこれらを組み込み関数として用意しているかというと、IntelがCore iシリーズからハミング重みを計算する`POPCNT`命令を追加しているため、これを利用できるようにするためだからです。

---

C++20で[`std::popcount`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/bit/popcount.html)として提供されるようになりました。